# Showing that the set $S = \{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2\mid ax^n + by^m < c\}$ for $n, m \in \mathbb{N}, a, b, c \in \mathbb{R}$,

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

Define the set $S = \{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2\mid ax^n + by^m < c\}$ for some fixed $n, m \in \mathbb{N}, a, b, c \in \mathbb{R}$ and suppose that $S\neq \varnothing$. How could I show that $S$ is open? Is it just as simple as stating that since $f(x, y) = ax^n + by^m$ is a continuous function and $S^c = f^{-1}[[c, \infty)]$, it follows that $S^c$ is closed and therefore $S$ is open?

How about if I wanted to do the proof via a good old neighbourhood proof, i.e. showing that for any $(x, y) \in S$ there exists $r > 0$ such that $B_r((x,y)) \subset S$? What should be my (at least initial) steps? I unfortunately lack the basic intuition to start to construct the required radius $r$ for $(x, y) \in S$.

Comment: Assume that $(x,y)\in S$. That means that $ax^n+by^n\lt c$. Consider the difference $\delta=c-\left(ax^n+by^n\right)$.  How much can $ax^n+by^n$ change for a given change in $x$ and $y$?

Comment: Yes, it's as simple as observing that $S$ is, by definition, the inverse image of an open set. You can do a "good old neighborhood proof here" but it will just be a specialization of the proof that polynomials are continuous. It is worth being able to prove that polynomials are continuous if you haven't done so.